# Angular mobileQuery.addEventListener is not a function in safari, how to fix?

Tags: ios, angular, safari, angular-material

I am using angular material sidenav and with it comes some breakpoints on maximum width of device.

here are the examples

- [Angular material documentation example](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples#sidenav-responsive)
- [The same example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xlvnlgjnngg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts)

It looks like this:

```
public mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher){
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addEventListener('change', this._mobileQueryListener);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeEventListener('change', this._mobileQueryListener);
}
```

On safari  I get this error :

> this.mobileQuery.addEventListener is not a function

Same goes for this.mobileQuery.removeEventListener.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

it's a check for browser compatibility

```
 if (this.mobileQuery?.addEventListener) {
      this.mobileQuery.addEventListener('change', this._mobileQueryListener);
    } else {
      this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
```

and

```
this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
```